# Laravel 5 - How to create an Artisan command to execute bash script

Tags: ubuntu, laravel-5

I want to get an artisan command to run a bash script when executed.

So I've created an artisan command using the following

`php artisan make:command backupList --command=backup:list`

And here is backupList.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; 

use Illuminate\Console\Command;


class backupDB extends Command
{

protected $signature = 'backup:list {name}';

protected $description = 'Database backup tool';



public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}



public function handle()
{
    $this->exec('ls -la');
}
}
```

In handle() exec and shell_exec don't seem to work, are there any alternatives to get the artisan command to run bash in shell?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Rather than use:

```
$this->exec('ls -la');
```

You can simply do the following:

```
// execute command
exec("ls -la", $output);

// print output from command
$this->comment( implode( PHP_EOL, $output ) );
```

Comment: That did it :D you are awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Since Laravel uses Symphony in core. You can use Symphony Components that are already implemented to Laravel. For this situation you can use this one

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html