# How to use redis "memory usage keyname" command with laravel facade redis? we can use all command except memory command

Tags: laravel, redis, predis, phpredis, laravel-facade

We can use below commands in laravel.

```
$user = Redis::get('user:profile:'.$id); 
$values = Redis::lrange('names', 5, 10);
$values = Redis::command('lrange', ['name', 5, 10]);
```

but can't use `memory usage keyname` command with laravel redis facade.

Answer (score 1):

The command is not defined for that, but you can use eval:

```
Redis::connection('connection')->eval("return redis.call('memory', 'usage', 'keyname')", 0)
```

Or if you want to use the keyname as a paramater:

```
Redis::connection('connection')->eval("return redis.call('memory', 'usage', KEYS[1])", 1, 'keyname');
```

Redis LUA scripts are executed the same way in laravel

Answer (score 0):

Short answer no you can't execute. Let me explain;

```
public function createCommand($commandID, array $arguments = array())
{
    $commandID = strtoupper($commandID);

    if (!isset($this->commands[$commandID])) {
        throw new ClientException("Command '$commandID' is not a registered Redis command.");
    }

    $commandClass = $this->commands[$commandID];
    $command = new $commandClass();
    $command->setArguments($arguments);

    if (isset($this->processor)) {
        $this->processor->process($command);
    }

    return $command;
}
```

this method is used when you invoke methods and it uses this abstract method to decide whether you can invoke a method or not.

```
abstract protected function getSupportedCommands();
```

`getSupportedCommands` method looks like this;

```
public function getSupportedCommands()
{
    return array(
        /* ---------------- Redis 1.2 ---------------- */

        /* commands operating on the key space */
        'EXISTS'                    => 'Predis\Command\KeyExists',
        'DEL'                       => 'Predis\Command\KeyDelete',
        'TYPE'                      => 'Predis\Command\KeyType',
        'KEYS'                      => 'Predis\Command\KeyKeys',
        'RANDOMKEY'                 => 'Predis\Command\KeyRandom',
        'RENAME'                    => 'Predis\Command\KeyRename',
        'RENAMENX'                  => 'Predis\Command\KeyRenamePreserve',
        'EXPIRE'                    => 'Predis\Command\KeyExpire',
        'EXPIREAT'                  => 'Predis\Command\KeyExpireAt',
        'TTL'                       => 'Predis\Command\KeyTimeToLive',
        'MOVE'                      => 'Predis\Command\KeyMove',
        'SORT'                      => 'Predis\Command\KeySort',
        'DUMP'                      => 'Predis\Command\KeyDump',
        'RESTORE'                   => 'Predis\Command\KeyRestore',
        ....
        ...
        ..
```

`memory usage` command is not available in this method. You may check `/vendor/predis/predis/src/Profile/RedisVersion300.php` or any other class in `Profile` folder - it is not defined in there.

The reason is `memory usage` method is available since Redis version `4.0.0`. This package is supporting commands until Redis version `3.0.0` as it can be seen from class names such as `RedisVersion240`, `RedisVersion300` etc.

Comment: thanks, for your answer but how do I know which key store how much memory? we can check by `memory usage keyname` in redis-cli but I want to display how much memory used by each key

Comment: it will be costly to scan all the `keys` in redis and executing `memory usage` one by one. I am not sure about the domain but you may try to run `redis-cli --bigkeys` to see some of the biggest ones depending on the data type(string, hash, sets etc) @parekhpankaj

Comment: @parekhpankaj please check this link https://gist.github.com/epicserve/5699837 (i am not the owner of this script) it looks like it covers your case.

Comment: I can't run this script in laravel. I need to run through the laravel controller and then need to display keys memory in view.

Comment: @parekhpankaj you shouldn't run this one regularly too. it has `keys` command. still if you want use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46208801/laravel-5-how-to-create-an-artisan-command-to-execute-bash-script - save the results in a text file/database table and in another method read from the file/database table